# Snort, add TCP retransmission rule

Tags: ids, snort, packet

Can somebody help me with adding rule for packet retransmission.

I found some documentation about the snort rules, but I am confused how to use it. The rules which catches the packet retransmission catches the original packet .

These are the packets for which I am trying to add the rule
[image]

This is the rule which suppose to catch the retransmission but also catches the original packets.

```
alert tcp any any -> <destinationAddress> 22 (msg:"SSH retransmission detected"; classtype: attempted0recon; sid: 999999)
```

Also, just for the sake of comparison, I want to try both rules to be mutual exclusive.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you've added a new custom attack class in your `classification.config` file with the name `attempted0recon`, [there isn't any such class in Snort by default](http://manual.snort.org/node31.html#SECTION00446100000000000000). There is however a class named `attempted-recon`.

You have also not set any additional filters for which the message *"SSH retransmission detected"* should be reported, so your example would read as:

> Alert with class `attempted0recon` and message *'SSH retransmission
>   detected'* any inbound TCP connection to `<destinationAddress>` port
>   22 originating from any remote address and port.

I didn't write it in exact order, as that would make it utterly unreadable, but the general Snort rules form is:

```
action proto src_ip src_port direction dst_ip dst_port (options)
```

Your rule could thus read like this:

```
alert tcp any any -> <destinationAddress> 22 (msg:"SSH retransmission detected"; 
                                              content:"TCP Retransmission"; 
                                              nocase; 
                                              classtype:attempted-recon;)
```

for your rule in the example you provided. Since the other (first packet) rule can't depend on any payload contents (as I don't see any in your printout), you could for example use [dsize keyword](http://manual.snort.org/node33.html#SECTION00467000000000000000) in the options part to identify them by their size and/or [other non-payload detections](http://manual.snort.org/node33.html#SECTION004623000000000000000):

```
alert tcp any any -> <destinationAddress> 22 (msg:"SSH key exchange"; 
                                              dsize: <518; 
                                              classtype:tcp-connection;)
```

Obviously, you could adopt these to suit your needs better and they are just examples.